# 2013 hyundai veloster instrument panel not working

Tags: hyundai, gauges, instrument-cluster

The instrument panel just quit working over night. Came out this morning and started the car but instrument panel lights and gauges not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since it sounds like everything else is working it could be the fuse has gone?

Comment: Fuses and relays are good